# Expanding a ViewGroup's surface to include text shadows

Tags: android, android-layout

In an Android project, I am using `FrameLayout` to contain a `TextView`. This `TextView` has a large shadow on it (to provide a glow). However, Android is detecting the `TextView`'s bounding rect to be just that of the contained text, without the shadow, and as a result the compositor gets confused when objects animate around it.

As a workaround I tried forcing the `TextView` to have its own hardware surface (with `setLayerType`), but this too is closely cropped to the text and doesn't account for the shadow, so the shadow gets cut off.

I have tried adding padding to the `FrameLayout`, but that doesn't expand the surface - it only moves the `TextView` down and right by the padding amount.

If I set a background color on the `FrameLayout`, the surface does expand to cover its entire size, but unfortunately this background is visible, even if I set it to `0x01000000`. If there were some way to force it to contain the entire background even if the background color is 0, that would be a suitable solution.

What is the easiest way to expand the hardware surface to include the text glow, ideally without affecting the position of the text itself?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but shouldn't you set a padding to a TextView?

Comment: @pskink You are not wrong. `setPaddingRelative()` seems to have worked. Thanks! Please write up an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: @pskink Never mind, I only thought it had worked but I'd accidentally disabled the hardware surface (which I realized when I saw the animation errors occur again) - as soon as I reenabled it, the same problem occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get `Canvas` to believe that every pixel has been touched, without actually having anything to paint. Simply drawing a `ColorDrawable` does not work, because every step along the way seems to detect that a fully-transparent color doesn't need to be rendered.  And, apparently the render for the text shadow is also only rendering where the canvas thinks it's been invalidated – so, for example, only drawing a couple of background pixels will expand the surface but still does not cause the actual text shadow to be rendered.

However, there is an operation that will cause `Canvas`'s clipping mask to get updated even with transparent pixels – a transparent `Bitmap`!

So, adding a background `Drawable` that renders out a transparent `Bitmap` has the desired effect. You can add a transparent bitmap as a resource (drawn using a `BitmapDrawable`), or you can do this:

```
final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(2, 2, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
final Paint bmpPaint = new Paint();
wrappingFrameLayout.setBackground(new Drawable() {
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
    public void draw(final Canvas c) {
        c.drawBitmap(bmp, null, getBounds(), bmpPaint);
    }
    public void setAlpha(final int a) {}
    public void setColorFilter(final ColorFilter cf) {}
});
```